# Alternative way to change mode-line

Tags: mode-line

Having tried to use `global-mode-string` to change the `mode-line` I have found a problem with the development version of emacs.  As it will take some time before a fix comes along, I would be grateful to have an alternative way that I can add and remove a list of strings on the mode line.

```
(push '("" "Test") global-mode-string)
```

"Test" in not being printed to the mode-line so I would need a different solution that changes the mode-line.

Comment: What is the problem? Have you reported it? If so, can you add a link to the bug report in your question?

Comment: "Test" does not show up in the mode-line when I execute the command in the scratch buffer.

Comment: What is maddening about your questions is that you don't give enough information to begin with, then when asked you provide some information about one of the questions asked as a comment; that leads to more questions and more comments. I have voted to close your question as "Needs additional details or clarity" and I will not change that until you provide all the information needed *IN YOUR QUESTION*. You have been told repeatedly that this is not a conversation site.

Comment: Also, you asked this question before and you were provided an answer which works for at least two people, but for some reason does not work for you: that is *NOT* necessarily a problem with the development version (and if it is, a bug report will get it fixed pronto), so it is disingenuous to pretend that this this the case. Even if it is, you can use the released version of Emacs or an earlier commit of the development version. Have you trried any of these approaches? If not, why not? If yes, why are there no details in your question about these attempts?

Comment: Because I need to use the newest versions for some of the functions I have to work.  So reverting to earlier commit is not an option.

Comment: You are naive to think that sending a bug report will get things fixed pronto.  Things don't happen this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just built an emacs from the latest sources (HEAD is commit  14d54212ea46dbd8c950c9852318597e0e47908d). I then started it with `src/emacs -Q` (I will not install it until I've run it for a while to make sure that nothing I care about is broken). Here's what it looks like:

[image]

I then ran

```el
(push '("" "Test") global-mode-string)
```

and here's what *that* looks like:

[image]

I did not need to force an update either.

It all looks as expected and there is no problem (well, there is, but not in the place you are looking at).

Comment: Hold on a little.  It does work as you say.  But I have a little screen and could not see the end part.

Comment: I would like to introduce the text at the beginning because of my small screen.

Comment: Stop wasting everybody's time (including yours).

Comment: AAAARGH! Changing the question in a comment to an answer is *ANOTHER* maddening habit of yours. STOP DOING THAT!

Comment: I will put a new question for it.  Never said I am changing the question in this answer.  Stop freaking out.

Comment: So your emacs windows all have fewer than 65 columns (noting that even a standard 80 column terminal would have been totally fine), meaning your default mode line was already entirely (and visibly!) consuming all of the space available to it, and *at no point* in this (frankly ridiculous) sequence of questions did it occur to you that (a) maybe the fact that the mode line was *already occupying all of the space* might be relevant to your seeming inability to add new information to it; or (b) that this constraint could be worth mentioning to the people spending their time trying to help.